# Apache2 stopped without any obvious reason

Tags: apache-httpd, dns, amazon-ec2, crash

This morning I had a call that on one of the servers the web server is not working. Restarting the apache2 process fixed the problem, but I can't understand the reason for the crash.

I've checked all logs, and the only relevant information about the accident is in the `error.log`:

```
[Tue Feb 07 06:25:39.804775 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16376] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ourdomain.com
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Feb 07 06:25:59.749847 2017] [unique_id:alert] [pid 16376] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH01564: unable to find IPv4 address of "ourdomain.com"
[Tue Feb 07 06:26:09.760784 2017] [:emerg] [pid 16376] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.000663 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity for Apache/2.8.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001311 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.1"; loaded version="1.5.1"
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001317 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.35 "; loaded version="8.39 2016-06-14"
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001324 2017] [:warn] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: Loaded PCRE do not match with compiled!
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001326 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001328 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001330 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] Original server signature: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:50.001364 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call: "2.8.0,StanSoftWeb 6.22,1.5.1/1.5.1,8.35/8.39 2016-06-14,Lua 5.1,2.9.1,82"
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:51.420554 2017] [:notice] [pid 4841] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call successfully sent. For more information visit: http://status.modsecurity.org/
[Tue Feb 07 11:44:52.000688 2017] [core:warn] [pid 4848] AH00098: pid file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

We didn't intentionally requested a greceful restart for sure. The server is AWS EC2 instance if that matters. I'm seeing this graceful restart in the logs every few hours, but without issues - the web server was operating good for months, no configuration changes in the meantime.

`AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting` is the line I can't explain to myself.

I'm out of ideas, can anyone suggest what's the reason for the crash?

Comment: Why do you characterize a "graceful restart" as a "crash"?

Comment: I do not. But `AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting` effectively killed the server, and I can't understand what happened. The configuration is not changed, restarting the server works without changing anything.

Comment: Is your DNS supposed to be working? I mean, is this on a private LAN where DNS hasn't been set up? If not, then the lines toward the top of the log snippet would seem to be important.

Comment: The DNS server in use is the one provided by Amazon, and I can't see any announcements for issues from them, but its not impossible. It works right now for sure. If that is the cause, how can I prevent this from happening again? Would hardcoding in `/etc/hosts` the IPv4 addresses which we use for the domains make any difference?

Comment: I've used the solution in http://serverfault.com/a/715719/184821 based on the hint provided by @WarrenYoung Do you want to post an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Partially related: based on the timing of the attempted graceful restart, this *might* be happening every day after logrotate rotates the logs, and you just happened to coincide with a connectivity disruption.  Check other days' logs around the same time to verify, and that part of the issue may be explained.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yup I already discovered that. Thanks for the heads-up. Murphy's law in place again. Indeed its a coincidence that exactly when the rotation was taking place, Amazon's DNS servers failed to reply.

Comment: Or the DNS Servers hosting your domain, if it's hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few lines in your log show that your DNS wasn't available, which Apache needs to be available so it can look up your site's [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) given the IP address(es) you've told it to bind to. (And it needs *that* in order to handle the HTTP/1.1 `Host` header, among other things.)

That gives you several possible solutions:

1. Use the `ServerName` directive to give Apache the FQDN explicitly, as the log entry suggests. Then you don't need DNS.
2. Make sure your DNS stays up. Standard practice is to use [at least two DNS servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/297318/why-should-one-have-a-secondary-dns-server), ideally geographically-separated, so that if one server or route to that server goes down, the other is still available.

   DNS slows down badly when this happens as systems time out waiting for their first DNS packets to time out before trying the second, but at least things eventually do proceed. DNS caching helps here.

   There are many companies that do nothing but supply secondary DNS for you, so you don't have to set up a whole other data center, or rent a whole EC2 instance or VPS just to stand up a secondary DNS server. Many other companies provide secondary DNS as one of their general suite of Internet hosting services.
3. Use your OS's `/etc/hosts` file to map IPs to domain names, and tell your OS's name resolver to [use that information preferentially](https://serverfault.com/questions/389920/apache-wont-start-unable-to-find-ipv4-address-of-none/715719#715719) to DNS. This is not only faster than DNS, its lifetime is inherently tied to that of your Apache host machine. About the only way for it to "go down" is for someone to fat-finger an edit to `/etc/hosts`.

   If you choose this option, consider doing the above options as well. You want secondary DNS anyway, and there's no particular reason to force Apache to do reverse lookups on IPs to figure out host names in the first place, since it's not information that's likely to change.